# JavaFX NumberAxis displays doubles

Tags: javafx

I've create a small app which uses a live animated line chart to display the number of files in a certain folder every 2 seconds. All works well but the chart/yAxis keeps displaying double values after every update. The folder can contain between 0 and 30.000 files ...

[image]

```
@FXML
public LineChart<String, Integer> myChart;

@FXML
public CategoryAxis xAxis;

@FXML
public NumberAxis yAxis;

...

yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
```

How do I make sure the y-Axis only contains/uses integer values ... ?
The x,5 values/rows should never be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tick unit is automatically set if autoranging is enabled (which it is by default). See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#tickUnitProperty).

So one way is to turn off autoranging, and set the range manually. This may need you to update the range when the data change, but the following demonstrates the idea:

```
public class ChartTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        Random rng = new Random();
        XYChart.Series<String, Integer> data = new XYChart.Series<>();
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (String x : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("")) {
            int y = rng.nextInt(10);
            if (y > max) max = y ;
            data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, y));
        }

        yAxis.setUpperBound(max + 1);

        data.setName("Data");
        LineChart<String, Integer> chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.getData().add(data);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(chart), 600, 800);
        stage.setTitle("Chart Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to retain autoranging, you can use a tick label formatter that returns an empty string for non-integer values:

```
public class ChartTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Number number) {
                double d = number.doubleValue();
                if (d == Math.rint(d)) {
                    return Integer.toString(number.intValue());
                }
                return "" ;
            }

            // Not used
            @Override
            public Number fromString(String s) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        Random rng = new Random();
        XYChart.Series<String, Integer> data = new XYChart.Series<>();
        for (String x : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("")) {
            int y = rng.nextInt(10);
            data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, y));
        }

        data.setName("Data");
        LineChart<String, Integer> chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.getData().add(data);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(chart), 600, 800);
        stage.setTitle("Chart Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]